What are the clearest definitions of phenomenology and existentialism?
I'm trying to get an understanding of phenomenology and existentialism.
My main questions are, what are the precise definitions of phenomenology and existentialism?
Here's my current starting point.
Phenomenology is the study of phaenomena.
φαινόμενα (phaenomena) = φαινό + με + να
φαινό = appear
με = with
να = look there
This, the etymology of phaenomena is, to appear with a look over there.
Using the etymology, Phenomenology is the study of how things appear with a look.
Now Husserl defined phenomenology more generally as the study of the essence of awareness of things.
You can be aware of self, sensations, thoughts, imaginations, emotions, desires, and actions.
Husserl's methodology allowed one to 'bracket' or suspend questions of being to focus on questions of appearances of any sort to an individual mind.
Later, Sartre coined the phrase "existence precedes essence."
One of my questions is what did Sartre mean by that?
Another question is, "Does Husserlian phenomenology maintain that essence precedes existence?"
My last question is, does phenomenology offer a grand unifying principle for philosophy in the sense that it claims to have paramount importance among the following branches of philosophy

phenomenology
ontology
epistemology
logic
ethics


Many a philosopher and thinker have made an -ology or an -ism. When it's named after the notable eg Marxism, Platonism no one starts with the etymology of Marx or Plato. Non proper noun based words like phenomenology and Existentialism are more meaningful... but only slightly.  IOW starting with a word analysis is not usually the best way of approaching the question. (You have my upvote, just thought I'd explain one possible reason for the downvote). Funnily. I notice that auto spell check capitalized my E in Existentialism!! Speaks a great deal if you think on it...

Precise definitions may have limited applicability for a field that questions the entirety, e.g. from Heidegger's What is a Thing? p3: "by metaphysics we do not mean a special field or branch within philosophy in contrast to logic and ethics. There are no fields in philosophy because philosophy itself is not a field. Something like a division of labor is senseless in philosophy; scholastic learning is to a certain extent indispensable to it but is never its essence."

read https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phenomenology/

@IoannisPaizis, I read that twice before I asked the question here.  I would rate the article a 7, on a scale of 1-10, it was a bit muddled here and there.  I'm not sure what they meant by 'experience', since the dictionary definition didn't substitute well.

I think that phenomenology is now rephrased as the study of consciousness.
